# What is the regular expression for String which may contains symbols like a-z 0-9 A-Z ( ) , . -

Tags: java, regex, string

I want the regular expression for the following scenarios.
If the string contains the following string that showed below, it should return true.

`a-z  0-9  A-Z  (      )    ,   .   -`

Comment: An easy enough task. What have you tried?

Comment: Is this a homework assignment?

Comment: @B Narasimha just a hint `String regex = "^[a-zA-Z0-9,._]*";`

Comment: @ankur-singhal Not a very good hint, though, as it doesn't really relate to the question.

Answer (score 1):

Try using

```
/^[ A-Za-z0-9.,-]*$/
```

Answer (score 0):

see demo here https://regex101.com/r/nQ6aX4/2

```
/^([a-zA-Z0-9\(\)\,\.\-]*)$/gm
```

Comment: What's the group for? And note that all those escapes are unnecessary within a class.

Answer (score 0):

you should try looking into `String` class which has method named `matches` with its use you can get to know it here

```
string.matches("[^A-Za-z0-9(),.-]*")
```

it will return true if match found or else false

Comment: You should escape reserved characters: (  )  ,  .  -